# Effective way of searching buggy error-handling constructions (regexes, parsers, etc.)

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, exception, error-handling

I'd like to search through thousands of c# code files, to find any broken blocks where exceptions are possibly taken under the cover and simply annihilated. I need some regular expression which is able to find constructions similar to this:

```
catch{}, catch(Exception e){}, try{}finally{}, ...
```

...including line breaks, redundant white spaces, etc.

Further analysis for `catch` statements which doesn't contain e.g. "*log*" phrases (which could indicate any kind of logging attempts) will be even more helpful - can possibly reveal more disturbing places:

```
catch(Exception){
    var x = ..
    // some other code without "log" phrase, which could indicate any error logging
}
```

Regards

Comment: Are you looking to use these regexes in Visual Studio from the find dialog? If so these are not "normal" regexes, which may affect the answer.

Comment: No I can actually write separate console tool for that.

Comment: You need a parser, not a regex.

Comment: If I need a parser, are there any free out there I can use to analyze the code ?

Comment: I understand that the second part with additional checking make it hard to write the regex. If so I can give up that case.

Comment: Use notepad++, along with regex.

Comment: Actually the regex is what I need.

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/roslyn.aspx